# 'str' object has no attribute 'p' using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, python-3.5

I have been following a tutorial on using BeautifulSoup, however when I try to read the title or even paragraphs (using soup.p) I get an error saying, "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*****/Tutorial1.py", line 9, in 
    pTag = soup.p
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'p'"

I am still very new to Python, sorry to bother if these is too much of an easy issue but I will greatly appreciate any help. Code given below:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/netball/33717953')    as response:
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
    soup = soup.prettify()
    pTag = soup.p

    print(pTag)
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? The error message seems clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing)

> The prettify() method will turn a Beautiful Soup parse tree into a nicely formatted **Unicode string**, with each HTML/XML tag on its own line.

You set an string to `soup` var here: `soup = soup.prettify()`. Of course a string has not `p` property, then crashes.

To find all `p`s:

```
...
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html5lib")
for paragraph in soup.find_all('p'):
    do_something_with(paragraph)
```

Comment: Oh so soup.prettify() is a string not a parse tree, thanks @danihp